# How can I make a double hover effect? #1 hover parent to change child. #2 hover child to change child

Tags: html, css

When I hover the the parent I want the opacity of the child element to be at 0.3 (initial 0).
Then when hover the child I want the opacity of the child to be 1.

But what I've tried the hover on the parent seems to overwrite the hover-effect of the child.

This is what I've tried.
HTML:

```
<div class="forwardArrowContainer">
   <h2>JavaScript</h2>
   <a href="/learnJS.html"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-right fa-2x forwardArrow"></i></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.forwardArrowContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative; 
}

.forwardArrow {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.forwardArrowContainer:hover .forwardArrow{
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.forwardArrow:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    color: rgba(209, 130, 34, 1);
    transition-duration: 1s;

}
```

Comment: `.forwardArrowContainer:hover .forwardArrow` has a higher specificity than `.forwardArrow:hover`, so the first selector wins. Make the second one `.forwardArrowContainer .forwardArrow:hover` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might work for you, I have override the opacity property of the child using !important as the parent styles were applying to it.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease; /* Add a smooth transition effect */
}

.parent:hover .child {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.child:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Parent
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nishant Fulara!!
This work out pretty fine :-)

Comment: Hi can you please mark the answer as accepted answer.